# Lua/LuaJIT decompilation challenge

Tags: lua, luajit

I have stumbled upon a Lua script which I am trying to decompile. So far I have tried all different versions of standard Lua decompilers such as `unluac` and `luadec`. I either get a "not a precompiled chunk" or "bad header in precompiled chunk" errors.

I have also tried different Lua versions and 32-bit and 64-bit architectures for the decompilers.

I have looked at the header and it reads something like this - `1b 4c 4a 01 02 52 20 20` in hex. Looks almost correct but it seems to me like the signature starts with one extra byte and the 6th and 7th byte are wrong. Also, there is 52 in there which I assume is the Lua's version.

As the signature is one byte too long, the normal decompilers don't work. I have a suspicion that this might me a LuaJIT bytecode as if you convert that string to ANSI you will notice `ESC, L, J` sequence which is a function header for LuaJIT.

In case this is a LuaJIT binary, where do I start about decompiling it? I have tried some decompilers but they all seem to be extremely out of date or fail at some point within the execution (I am talking about LJD and its derivatives).

Any suggestions on how to analyze, view opcodes or decompile it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the file I am talking about (apologies, too long to post here in case someone wants to have a go):

https://pastebin.com/eeLHsiXk
https://filebin.net/r0hszoeh8zscp8dh

Comment: Please upload the bytecode file to a file hosting service (not text sharing service), because the file is binary.

Comment: What software is able to run this bytecode?

Comment: The bytecode looks like a LuaJIT 2.0 bytecode. `0x52` is the size of the first proto.  It's not a Lua version.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Hi Egor, thank you for your input. Apologies for the delay, here's the file: https://filebin.net/r0hszoeh8zscp8dh